# How to play an audio file on dialogflow using firebase function

Tags: google-cloud-functions, dialogflow-es

I have my own server where audio file is uploaded. [www.theislam360.me:8080/hbd.mp3](http://www.theislam360.me:8080/hbd.mp3)
I want to play this audio on google home using firebase functions.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
var request1 = require('request')
exports.webhook = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {

        console.log("request.body.result.parameters: ", request.body.result.parameters);

        let params = request.body.result.parameters;

        var options = {
            url: `https://theislam360.me/${params.any}`+".mp3",
            json:true
        }
        request1(options, function(error, res, body){
            if(error) response.send({speech: "error in API call"});
            else response.send({speech: "<speak>This is the audio <audio>www.theislam360.me:8080/hbd.mp3</audio></speak>"});
        });
    });
```

I am getting Internal server error on dialogflow fulfillment. Here is the firebase logs.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was as simple as this

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

exports.webhook = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    response.send({speech:`<speak>Welcome to my action! <audio src="https://theislam360.me:8080/hbd.mp3"></audio> How can I help you?</speak>`})
});
```

Note that the server should be `https`, the audio file is stored in.

Answer (score 2):

The error

> Cannot read property "parameters" of undefined

is telling you that `request.body.result` is undefined which means that there is no property named "result" on the `request.body` object. Try double checking that the parameters you are looking for is indeed in the `request.body.result` object.